# Iframe with src="javascript:document.write" IE9 open popup

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer, iframe

I am develop browser widget which should run on all sites.
I am append iframe this way, for avoid IE9 security problems:

```
var iframe = document.createElement('iframe');
document.body.appendChild(iframe);
iframe.src = "javascript:document.write('<script>document.domain=\"" + document.domain + "\"</script>')";
```

And all seems good, but if you go to http://taobao.com and run this code in IE9, you get popup with `<script>document.domain=\"" + document.domain + "\"</script>` url.
On many other site everything fine.

Where is the problem?

Thanks for attention.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem is fixed.
Tag `<base> with target="_blank"` open new popup.
`document.getElementsByTagName('base')[0].target = '_self';` fix this.